# How to set inner divs width as percentage with a margin

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a mobile version for my website and I'm coming across a problem. I have an outer div that I want to stretch across the entire width, and then I want 4 divs inside of that to be of equal width, with a margin inbetween them.

This would be easy if I did not need a margin between them. I would simple set `width:25%` and be done with it, but I want a 3 pixel margin between them. When you set this margin, the actual widths will be more than 100%, therefor taking up more than one line in the div.

I thought about trying to set a negative `margin-left`, but this just gets rid of the margin on the right.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
width:300px;
height:50px;
background-color:#f00;
}

.inner {
width:25%;
margin-right:2px;

float:left;
background-color:#00f;
}
```

And here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5mgD/) so you can see exactly what I mean.

By the way, I know that I could use some jQuery or JavaScript to accomplish this after the page loads, but I wanted to know if there is a purely CSS way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `calc()` to subtract `2px` from the widths of the elements.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/SdzsW/1/)

```
.inner {
    width:calc(25% - 2px);
}
```

However, this results in a `2px` margin on the last element. To fix this, add in:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/SdzsW/)

```
.inner:last-child {
    width:25%;
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could just use percentage based margins.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I had no idea of this "calc" function in css. Do you know if this will maintain the value that it initially calculates, or is it update if the screen resolution is changed (for example switching from portrait to landscape, will it update the width correctly?)

Comment: @jas7457 It would update. Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/SdzsW/2/) -- resize the browser to see it dynamically update based on the width percentage.. Aside from that, as Danko points out - it is [not supported by IE8 and lower](http://caniuse.com/calc) but I really wouldn't worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use % for your margins too.  IE:

```
margin: 0 0 0 1%;
```

Just make sure to compensate the margin with a decrease in width.  So instead of 25% for "inner" class, you would use 24% for the above margin implementation.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5mgD/1/) incorporating the above

Answer (score 1):

You could make the columns spread 24% and do a % based margin between them.

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%
    height:50px;
    background-color:#f00;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.inner {
    width:24%;
    margin:0 .5%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#00f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `border` and `box-sizing` to include this 2px gap inside your 25% width.

If background is not a plain color, then border should be transparent and background-color drawn as inset shadow.

```
.inner {
    width:25%;
    border-right:2px solid transparent;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
 box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 10000px #00f;/* make it big , so it doesnt matter wich size it becomes.*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g5mgD/4/
width a background-image and a translucid color http://jsfiddle.net/g5mgD/9/

Answer (score 0):

I would divide the 100% within elements and the margin like so:

```
.inner {
    width:24%;        
    margin: 0.5%;    

    float:left;
    background-color:#00f;
}
```

If you want the outer margins and the inner margins to be of the same size, you may assign specific margins to the first element.